# Not injective given cardinalities of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

How do I prove that a function $f:G \rightarrow H$ is not one-to-one if $|G|=20$ and $|H|=24$?

Comment: This isn't true, it can be an injection. Although using letters $G$ and $H$ hints that you may be dealing with two groups and a group homomorphism. In this case it really cannot be injective, it follows from Lagnange's theorem.

Comment: Yes, I'm dealing with a group homomorphism - good guess! How does it follow from Lagrange's theorem? Is it because |G| does not divide |H|?

Comment: Exactly. If $f$ were injective, then $|f(G)|$ would be equal $20$. But $f(G)$ is a subgroup in $H$, so its order must divide 24. A contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prove that $f$ is not one-to-one. It may very well be.

What you *can* prove is that $f$ is not onto (surjective).

---

Aside:

If you are working with a group homomorphism $f: G\to H$, with groups $G, H$, then the homomorphism $f$ cannot be an isomorphism because it is neither injective (use Lagrange's Theorem) nor surjective.

Answer (score 0):

It can be injective. Just leave out 4 elements of $H$. Make a 1-1 correspondence with the 20 elements left. We have a 1-1.

It might not be 1-1 if 2 points in $G$ map to $H$.

It is not onto, clearly.